# How to get the value of variables in centos7 repo file?

Tags: bash, centos7

```
cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

The following lines were displayed,it is a shell script.

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

To input `echo $releasever` in terminal,nothing output in the screen.

How to get the value of $releasever ,$arch,$basearch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't shell variables, so you would not expect to be able to print them in bash.  These are values that are provided by `yum`.  [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/yum-how-can-i-view-variables-like-releasever-basearch-yum0) discusses how to get them programatically, but in general:

- `releasever` is the major version of your CentOS release; basically, `rpm -q --qf='%{VERSION}\n' centos-release`
- `basearch` is your system architecture, which you can find with `uname -m`
- There is no `arch` variable
- `infra` is apparently something new and may not be used, based on [this post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=49377)

There is some documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Using_Yum_Variables.html), which while old-ish is still accurate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command:

```
python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)'
```